# How to integrate VeeValidate with vue-i18n?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate, vue-i18n

With a click event i change the vue-i18n language i want to change the vee-validate dictionary to the same language

**main.js**

```
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate'
import validations from './validations.js'
import i18n from './lang'
Vue.use(VeeValidate)
new Vue({
   router,
   store,
   i18n,
   render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

vue-i18n folder > lang/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import en from './locals/en'
import es from './locals/es'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  messages: {
    en: {
      lang: en
    },
    es: {
      lang: es
    }
  }
})
```

vee-validate folder > src/validations.js

```
import {Validator} from 'vee-validate'
const dictionary = {
    en: {
        custom: {
            signupEmail: {
                required: 'Error',
            },
              
        }
    },
    es: {
        custom: {
            signupEmail: {
                required: 'Hubo un error',
            },
              
        }
    }    
}
Validator.localize(dictionary)
const validator = new Validator()
validator.localize('en')
export default Validator
```

**Im trying to target the validator.localize('en') and i cant change to the es dictionary, even if i change it manually validator.localize('es'). What im missing?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out myself how to do it.

In the App.vue set inside the mounted cycle hook

```
VeeValidate.Validator.locale = `${language}`
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're close, but missing a few key pieces.

You can [pass an object](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/localization.html#vuei18n-integration) like this when you wire up VeeValidate:

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate, {
   i18nRootKey: 'custom', // customize the root path for validation messages.
   i18n,
   dictionary: {
    en: {
    custom: {
        signupEmail: {
            required: 'Error',
        },        
      }
    },
    es: {
    custom: {
        signupEmail: {
            required: 'Hubo un error',
        },    
       }
     }
   }
});
```

Obviously I just put your dictionary inline here, it would be much better to keep it as a separate file and import it that way.

Comment: hi @maxshuty i think stil im missing something, this is what i did with your code, 1. comment validations.js 2. Add your code to the main.js 3. change the language and still getting only english

Comment: @AlexHunter are you positive that your language is actually triggering the change you think it is?

Comment: of course, actually im changing languages at the same time with moment.js and vue-i18n, but i cant make it work with veevalidate

Comment: Are you loading VeeValidate _before_ i18n into the Vue instance?

Comment: yes, as you can see in the main.js, i added your code and change it for   Vue.use(VeeValidate) and nothing happens @maxshuty

Comment: @AlexHunter there must be something else in play here if you have the code I added and it's still not working. Can you verify that the `i18nRootKey` is setup correctly with your dictionary?

Comment: its the correct i18nRootKey. I think the problem is with the configuration of the dictionary @maxshuty what do you think?

Comment: @AlexHunter I just realized that I am on v2.x of VeeValidate and my logic may not apply to 3+. What version are you on? Here is a sandbox for the more recent stuff: https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-30-vuei18n-integration-9vs4l?from-embed=&file=/src/components/Example.vue. Do you have i18n setup

Comment: im using version 2, and yes i saw that codesanbox and cant make it work

Comment: @maxshuty can you show within in your provided codesandbox some example with using vee-validate, i18n and local messages files (eg.: locals/en.json) ?

Comment: @Luc you could just `import en from '../locals/en` and then inside of the dictionary here `en: en`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Kind of did it :) https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-30-vuei18n-integration-forked-lsmzs?file=/src/components/Example.vue